# Set boolean for a function inside a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, boolean

```
//     openMNav.isDropDown = false;
       var openMNav = function () {                         
              if (!this.isDropDown) {
              this.isDropDown = true;
              console.log(1);
            } else {    
              this.isDropDown = false;
              console.log(0);                          
        }
```

My question is how to do something like this: `var openMNav.isDropDown = false;`.
I want to set openMNav -> isDropDown outside the function to false

Comment: I'm wondering what do you want to achieve? If you are going to change object value why not using Object instead of function?

Comment: i want to do this: this.isDropDown = false;   at the very top of the code

Comment: openMNav is a constructor function, not an object at this point. So anything you assign on top of that will not be set to `this`, but to the function itself

Comment: so there is no way to change the boolean to false outside the function?

Comment: @KarlHusten, the one you have is a constructor, which can be instantiated like `const nav = new openMNav()`, if you want something plain use an object: `openMNav = {isDropDown: false}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to set on the function itself, you should just use openMNav in the function not this.

```
function openMNav () {

    if (!openMNav.isDropDown) {
        console.log('do open');
        openMNav.isDropDown = true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('already opened');
        openMNav.isDropDown = false;
    }
}

openMNav();
openMNav();
```

Comment: if you want to change the boolean out of the function, just change it openMNav.isDropDown = false;